# Is it possible to stop myself from breaking bedrock in creative?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to plan a farm near bedrock in the overworld.

I created a copy of the word location and I would like to plan the farm in creative, then build it in survival with the help of litematica.

The issue is that sometimes I make a mistake and break a bedrock block.

Of course in survival this won't be doable, making my planning pointless if I mess up.

Is there some command that I can put in a command block to stop me from breaking bedrock and/or replacing bedrock as soon as it is broken?

Comment: Assuming you're familiar with scoreboard and objectives.
/scoreboard objectives add minecraft.broken:minecraft.bedrock
Can be used to detect bedrock being broken
(Doesn't answer the question so it's in comments)

Comment: You could probably use AlexJaynMF's scoreboard command to detect where it was and simply fill that spot with bedrock

Comment: @Diehe if you could write an answer detailing how to do that, I would accept it (but I have no familiarity with the scoreboard system)

Comment: I left this a comment as I myself am not familiar enough with these commands to be able to answer properly.

Comment: @Federico i well answer this question give me like 10 mintues i am busy at the moment

Comment: @circusbaby23 there is no rush. take 10 hours, days, whatever if you need

Comment: There's another method: Keep /fill -ing the places that have bedrock, using a repeating, doesn't need redstone command block. However, it's impractical if the "shape" of the bedrock in your farm is irregular.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a mod called tweakaroo you can make breaking restrictions.

Comment: Hi again! Please add the relevant information from the video into your answer, so it will remain relevant. Link-only answers tend to get deleted :)

Answer (score -2):

You can try holding a sword. Swords don't break stuff in creative.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).